# In Ember, how do I bind an attribute whose name has a colon?

Tags: xml, ember.js, svg, ember-components

I want to create a component whose root element is

```
<svg width='150px'
     height='150px'
     viewBox='0 0 150 150'
     version='1.1'
     xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
     xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'>
```

I can set most of those up with simple attribute bindings:

```
Ember.Component.extend({
  attributeBindings: [ 'height', 'version', 'viewBox', 'width', 'xmlns' ],
  tagName: 'svg',
  height: '150px',
  version: '1.1',
  viewBox: '0 0 150 150',
  width: '150px',
  'xmlns:xlink': 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
});
```

The one that won't work is `xmlns:xlink`. If I try to add that as an attribute binding, Ember interprets the colon to mean *bind the `xlink` attribute to the value of the `xmlns` property* so I get

```
<svg width='150px'
     height='150px'
     viewBox='0 0 150 150'
     version='1.1'
     xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
     xlink='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
```

How can I set up an attribute binding for this property?

Comment: maybe you should name property `'xmlns:xlink': 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'`

Comment: xmlns attributes aren't real, they are an expression of the namespace the element is in. For instance if you change an xmlns value the element's namespace won't change.

Comment: I bound the value with ''xlink:xmlns:xlink''. Isn't this what u need? http://emberjs.jsbin.com/teteyu/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @Bek I actually did and had mistyped it here. Edited.

Comment: @blessenm if you write that up as an answer, I'll accept it! I figured the two colons would confuse Ember even further and dismissed the idea.

Comment: @RobertLongson I don't actually need it bound, but until Ember.Components have the root element in the template, `attributeBindings` is the only way to emit attributes into the root element on first render.

Comment: @JamesA.Rosen What do you mean by 'even further'? Just curious.

Comment: @blessenm I thought `xlink:xmlns:xlink` would set the `xlink` attribute to `"xmlns"` if truthy and `"xlink"` if falsy, like class bindings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it as below

```
attributeBindings: ['xlink:xmlns:xlink'],
xlink: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'
```

This should generate `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` in your component.

**[Here is the working demo.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/teteyu/2/edit?html,js,output)**